# Converting attributes of class to a django models subclass

Tags: django, python-3.x, class, subclass

I have a bunch of classes that I'm now trying to incorporate into `django`.

For example, I have a `Base` class that all my other classes derive from:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, label: str = 'Base'):
        self.label = label
```

An example of a sublcass would be a `Person` class:

```
from typing import Any, Dict

class Person(Base):
    def __init__(self, name: str, attributes_to_options: Dict[str, Any], **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.attributes_to_options = attributes_to_options
```

I would use this as:

```
alex = Person(name='Alex', attributes_to_options={'age': 10, 'is_happy': True}, label='Person:Alex')
```

My question is, **how do I incorporate such a class into `django`?** Is it as simple as inheritting from `models.Model`? e.g.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(Base, models.Model):
    def __init__(self, name: str, attributes_to_options: Dict[str, Any], **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.attributes_to_options = attributes_to_options
```

But then how do I specify the `models.CharField` for the two attributes `name` and `attributes_to_options`?

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Have you tried declaring `name = models.CharField(...)` etc in the Person class scope? The important thing is that model fields must be declared in a class that inherits from `models.Model`.

Comment: You can have an [abstract base mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)l that implements some fields, like "label"

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use a CharField for the attributes_to_option attribute, since that is a dictionary. If you do want that, you would have to convert it to a string before saving. If you are using postgresql, you shoud consider using JSONField instead of CharField.

Comment: Passing dictionaries as parameters is nearly always a bad idea... a dictionary is a key/value store not a mobile namespace

Comment: @IainShelvington I guess because I wanted to have an arbitrary number of `attribute` values with their corresponding `options` ...

Comment: @alex_lewis the issue with passing a dictionary around as an object/namespace is that when you or anyone else comes to debug your code you will just see a dictionary passed in to the function with no idea what is in it, then you have to trawl up the stack and maybe find where that key was set or maybe not, I have been there and it is not fun. Explicit parameters to functions may be slightly more restrictive but save a lot of debugging effort

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks for the suggestion -- I'll rethink my  strategy ..,

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that in general, any Django `Model` subclass corresponds to a database table. Inheriting from such a class ("concrete inheritance") means that another database table will be created with a one-to-one linkage between rows, and that every query will implicitly perform a join in the DB. This is bad for performance. But for tables with not very many rows or for tables queried infrequently, you possibly don't need to care.

Django provides two special cases that can be defined via the `Meta` class in the `Model` subclass. The first is an "Abstract Base Class" which allow you to define a bunch of stuff which will be present in any derived model. IN the case of fields, they are "copied" into the class that inherits them, rather than having their own DB table. The second is a "Proxy" class, which allows you to place a new set of methods on top of an existing database table, and which goes some way towards allowing polymorphic models. Careful reading of the Django doc. is a good idea.

I have experimentally established that one can also use mix-in classes in the same way as one uses them with class-based views. In other words,

```
class ExtraMethodsMixin( object): # NB must inherit from object
    # NB no model field definitions allowed here
    @property
    def something_or_other(self):
         return something_based_on_model_fields_defined_elsewhere
    #etc.
```

and then

```
class Foo( ExtraMethodsMixin, models.Model): # NB mixin goes first
    # define names and fields that the ExtraMethodsMixin uses
    #   (and anything else that a Foo needs)
    ...
```

The one snag I have found is that migrations do remember the dependency of `Foo` on  `ExtraMethodsMixin` and so it's a PITA should you desire to completely remove the mixin at a later date. However, you can stub it out to a single `pass` statement without any problems, so this is probably not a significant worry. My other worry is that this usage is completely undocumented (other than as standard Python), so it's just about possible that it's trampling on Django internals in some very subtle way I've not yet spotted. So I'm definitely a bit short of recommending this technique.

Comment: s/plugin class/mixin class/g